# Using kinect xbox 360 and kinect xbox one in a single application

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I want to use Kinect xbox 360 and kinect xbox one sensors in a single Unity application. They use different sdks (version 1.8 and version 2 respectively) and the namespaces are different.

However, I haven't received an answer that this cannot be done. Can I use the two sensors in a single unity application?
Can someone advise if I can use an sdk which supports both the sensors?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you can.

I have both SDK 1.8 and 2.0 installed and working on my PC, but I have not tried to use both the device in a single application.

However, you should consider that both the SDKs require a lot of computational resources (incuding GPU). And also, you need two distinct USB controllers to do so.

Having said that, I think there is nothing else that can avoid using both devices in a single application.

Good luck.